# Is there a way to do a distinct count with a condition on the grouped data in mysql faster

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query (MYSQL) that I would like to go faster. The general problem is to count distinct keys that has an aggregated condition on them. That is, I like to sum the values of a column in the rows with the same key value and then determine if it should be included in the count. The only solution I have come up with is to do a sub-query that do the summing and then count distinct in the outer query using having there. Like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT key), sum1, sum2, categoryid
 FROM
 (
SELECT SUM(cnt1) AS sum1,
       SUM(cnt2) AS sum2,
       key,categoryid
FROM table
GROUP BY key,categoryid
  ) as SUBQUERY  
GROUP BY  categoryid 
HAVING (8*sum1)/sum2 > 0;
```

The problem (as I see it) is that the query use a sub-query that will produce a temp table. As the data set large (10M rows, 500K distinct keys) it takes a lot of time. It looks like it should be possible to do better as a straight distinct count without the condition takes just a tenth of the time of this query and summing without grouping takes only a fraction of that.

Anyone with ideas on how to improve on performance?

Thanks in advance!

Lasse

Comment: Can you edit your question and show some sample data (spaces between data elements vs tabs), and show what you WANT as a final result...  Sample data might help give better insight for this question.

Comment: Don't really see what you need data for. The datatype is integers on everything. You can pretend that key  goes from one and up and categoryid is random between 1 - 4. I get the correct result so its not a question of the result, but of the speed I get it. To do a meaningful test you need at least 1000000 rows, so it is not possible to give you full table content.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to cut the response time myself by moving the count distinct to the inner query. Don't know why I didn't see that earlier. Obviously makes the temp table smaller. However it is still a factor 4-5 slower than the distinct count without a condition.

The new select looks like:

SELECT dist_cnt, sum1, sum2, categoryid
 FROM
 (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT key) AS dist_cnt,
       SUM(cnt1) AS sum1,
       SUM(cnt2) AS sum2,
       key,categoryid
FROM table
GROUP BY key,categoryid
  ) as SUBQUERY
WHERE (8*sum1)/sum2 > 0
GROUP BY  categoryid

Anyway, I think it should be possible to get it at least a factor 2 faster.
Lasse